# Exercise on Kronecker-Weber theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I’m trying to give a full proof oh the theorem following the last exercises of chapter 4 of Marcus Number fields and I would like  to solve  exercise 37, wich  should be an immediate application of the theorem:
Let $K$ an abelian extension of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $r$ the product of all integer primes that are ramified in $K$, with an extra factor of 2 if 2 is ramified. Prove that $K$ is contained in the $nr^{th}$ cyclotomic field.

I don’t know where to start, if someone could give me an hint I would appreciate it!

Comment: You might already have tried this, but I think if you trace through the exercises that prove Kronecker-Weber and keep track of the exact cyclotomic extensions involved this will come out. Each step of the proof basically produces a root of unity that accounts for a piece of the abelian extension in question, and then when you throw them all together you get a cyclotomic extension containing it.

Comment: The point is that the proof at the beginning reduced to the case of abelian extension of prime power order degree in which the prime involved is the only ramified. I cannot relate this tho the hypotheses.

Comment: See An Elementary Proof of the Kronecker-Weber Theorem
M. J. Greenberg,  The American Mathematical Monthly 81 (1974)